# JavaScript how can I add all the file sizes together?

Tags: javascript, file, file-upload, size

When I select the files I want, I want to alert all the sizes together. So if I upload 3 files and on is 100bytes and one is 200 bytes and one is 500 bytes. I want it to alert 800 bytes. At the moment its alerting each one at a time.

This is the function

```
function upload(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var file = document.getElementById("file");

    for(var i = 0; i < file.files.length; i++){
        var each = file.files[i];
        var sizes = each.size;

        alert(size);
    }

    startupload();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using alert inside the loop :

```
function upload(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var file = document.getElementById("file"),
        size = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < file.files.length; i++){
        var each = file.files[i];
        var sizes = each.size;
        size += sizes;
    }
     alert(size);

    startupload();
}
```

Comment: Oops, my bad, try now (notice the `size = 0` part)